# Communication between 2 Servlets is not working for a Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

Hi everyone im learning now how to work with Servlets and Databases by myself and single parts are working. But all together dont work because my DatabaseConnection Class isn't getting the Datas from my LoginServlet.

So Im getting the Datas from LoginServlet by Getter´s and if i run DatabaseConnection it fills a new row in my Database with "null" because i didn't send anything through my Registration page. My LoginServlet receives the Datas from Registration and checks if they are set correct when it is, the user will get send to a new Page. These are the single parts. And if i run the whole project i´ll don't get any errors, & glassfish tells me that LoginServlet received the Datas, DatabaseConnection is running but isn't showing anything in console & MySQL didn't received anything.

The second thing i like to know is why i can't properly set up a timestamp & SimpleDateFormater(to parse String birth)

Thanks for any help.

DatabaseConnection.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DatabaseConnection {

static boolean connection;
public LoginServlet ls = new LoginServlet();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginServlet ls = new LoginServlet();
    Connection conn = null;

    System.out.println("Im here");//not showing up
    try {
        String ausgabe = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/project";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
        System.out.println("Database connection wurde hergestellt ");

        // Manuelle Eingabe der Daten
        //  conn.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO `accounts` (`name`, `password`, `salt`,`createdat`,`birthday`,`gender`) VALUES ('Test4', 'bla','123','12-11-13 12:12:12','1994-11-12','1')"); //Insert a row
        System.out.println("DB: " + ls.username);
        conn.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO `accounts` (`name`, `password`, `salt`,`createdat`,`birthday`,`gender`) VALUES ('" + ls.username + "', '" + ls.password + "','123','12-11-13 12:12:12','1337-11-11','" + ls.gend + "')"); //Insert a row


        System.out.println("Clientinfo: " + conn.getClientInfo());
        System.out.println("Datenbank:  " + conn.getCatalog());
        System.out.println("MetaData:   " + conn.getMetaData());
        System.out.println("Warnungen:  " + conn.getWarnings());



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {

            try {
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Database connection beendet");

            } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
        }
    }
}
}
```

LoginServlet.java

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/loginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

String username, password, cpassword, email, birth, gender;
int gend;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // read form fields
    username = request.getParameter("username");
    password = request.getParameter("password");
    cpassword = request.getParameter("cpassword");
    email = request.getParameter("email");
    birth = request.getParameter("birth");
    gender = request.getParameter("gender");

    System.out.println("username: " + username);
    System.out.println("password: " + password);
    System.out.println("");


    CharSequence mySet = "@";
    CharSequence mys = "m";
    CharSequence wys = "w";

    boolean e = false;

    if (gender.contains(wys) || gender.contains(mys)) {
        e = true;

    } else if (gender.contains(wys)) {
        gend = 0;
    } else {
        gend = 1;
    }

    // get response writer
    //PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    if (password.equals(cpassword) && e) {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        // build HTML code
        String htmlRespone = "<html>";
        htmlRespone += "<h2>Dein Benutzername ist: " + username + "<br/>";
        htmlRespone += "Dein Password ist: " + password + "<br/>";
        htmlRespone += "Deine Email ist: " + email + "<br/>";
        htmlRespone += "Dein Geburtstag ist: " + birth + "<br/>";
        htmlRespone += "Dein Geschlecht ist: " + gender + "</h2>";

        htmlRespone += "</html>";

        // return response
        writer.println(htmlRespone);
    } else if (password != cpassword) {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        String htmlResponse = "<html>";
        htmlResponse += "Dein Passwort stimmt nicht überein";
        htmlResponse += "</html>";
        htmlResponse += "<a href=\"Registration.jsp\" target=\"links\">  Zurück</a>";



        writer.println(htmlResponse);

    } else if (e == false) {
    } else if (birth == null) {
        System.out.println("Geburtstag falsch formatiert");
    }

}

public String getUsername() {
    System.out.println("getter: " + username);
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getCpassword() {
    return cpassword;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getBirth() {
    return birth;
}

public int getGender() {
    return gend;
}

}
```

Registration.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<a href="index.jsp" target="links">Startseite</a>

    <div align="center"> 
        <br/>
        <form name="reg" method="POST" action="loginServlet"><p>
            <table width="370">
                <tr>
                    <td style="float: left;">Benutzername&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="float: right;"><input type="text" name="username" class='input' maxlength="12" placeholder="Benutzername" autocomplete="off" required autofocus>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="float: left;">Passwort:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="float: right;"><input type="password" name="password" class='input' maxlength="12" placeholder="Passwort" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="float: left;">Passwort Bestätigen:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="float: right;"><input type="password" name="cpassword" class='input' maxlength="12" placeholder="Passwort Bestätigen" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="float: left;">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="float: right;"><input type="text" class='input' name="email" placeholder="Email" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="float: left;">Geburtstag:<br><small>(YYYY-MM-DD)</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="float: right;"><input id="datepicker" type="text" maxlength="10" class='input' name="birth" placeholder="Geburtstag" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="float: left;">Geschlecht:<br><small>(m oder w)</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="float: right;"><input type="text" maxlength="1" class='input' name="gender" placeholder="Geschlecht" required></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Bestätigen" class="doVote button" style="" name="register">
            </p></form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you didn't understatnd that is YOU CAN'T create Request and Response objects of the Servlet.This is the work of Web Container so,Creating Servlet instance yourself is wrong.[Please study the Servlet life cycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/Servlets4.html).

This code is not giving ERROR because Servlet is also normal Class.